# Using Set-ADUser within a Function

Tags: function, powershell

Im having issues setting an attribute value in AD when using a function. When I use Set-ADUser under the same conditions without using a function I do not get an issue, it works great. When using Set-ADUser within a function I am getting an invalid argument error. I need to use a function as I am comparing a lot of data values. Alot of data is going to be compared this the need for a function. Im stumped.

```powershell
function compareandset($value_ad, $value_csv, $userid, $propdata) {
      $id = $userid.SamAccountName

      IF($value_ad -eq $value_csv) {
        Write-Host "The values were the same!"
      }
      ELSEIF($value_ad -ne $value_csv) {
           Write-Host "AD value changed"
           get-aduser -filter {SamAccountName -eq $userid} | Set-ADUser -$propdata $value_csv
      }
}

$userid = "jsmith"
$value_ad = "A city"
$value_csv = "Not a city"
$propdata = "Office"

compareandset $Office $office_csv_value $userid $propdata
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the full error message say? You can try using splatting and change:

```powershell
...
Write-Host "AD value changed"
get-aduser -filter {SamAccountName -eq $userid} | Set-ADUser -$propdata $value_csv
}
...
```

to:

```powershell
...
Write-Host "AD value changed"
$params = @{$propdata=$value_csv}
get-aduser -filter {SamAccountName -eq $userid} | Set-ADUser @params
}
...
```

More about splatting here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx

Comment: Thank you! spatting solved the issue.
I curious as to why this solved the issue. I have read and practices examples from the MS link you provided. Why would grouping the values resolve the issue only when using Set-ADUser within a function. The data is being found as seen in the full error message below.

Comment: jtest | Attribute:Office | Action:Changed | SAP: 22 | AD:Test Office
           Set-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '22'.
           At line:11 char:69
           +             get-aduser -filter {SamAccountName -eq $id} | Set-ADUser <<<<  -$propdata $value_csv
           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
           + FullyQualifiedErrorId :               PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

Comment: Perhaps `$propdata` is not being set correctly? You can verify by adding `Write-host "get-aduser -filter {SamAccountName -eq $userid} | Set-ADUser -$propdata $value_csv"` under `Write-Host "AD value changed"` to see if the command is what you expect to be.